# 301 redirect a page, but only if it doesn't have parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I have multiple pages that I need to 301 redirect, but only if it DOES NOT have the parameters ?embed=true in its url.

for example:

```
www.example.com/old-page.php should redirect to www.example.com/new-page.php
```

but

```
www.example.com/old-page.php?embed=true should not redirect at all
```

Can anyone please help? So far I have the following, but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^embed=true [NC]
RewriteRule ^/old-page.php$ /new-page.php [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/old-page2.php$ /new-page2.php [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !embed=true [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?old-page.php$ /new-page.php [L,R=301]
```

Try in Guest or Incognito mode after applying above rules.

Comment: didn't work :( 

I want: https://lingeriefc.com/wiki/Agatha_'Cannibal'_Carter
to redirect to:
https://lingeriefc.com/agatha-cannibal-carter/

but not: https://lingeriefc.com/wiki/Agatha_'Cannibal'_Carter?embed=true

Comment: please help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53893457/query-string-redirect-inside-wiki-folder?noredirect=1#comment94634105_53893457